# Query array of hashes with multiple values using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes as follows:

```
array = [{"name"=>"Nish", "age"=>27, "place"=>"xyz"},
         {"name"=>"Hari", "age"=>26, "place"=>"xyz"},
         {"name"=>"Anan", "age"=>28, "place"=>"xyz"}]
```

I want to select the hashes with `age  27 and 26`

How to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
array.select { |user| [26, 27].include?(user['age']) }
```

The 'select' will choose any elements that match the provided block.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of **`between?`**

```
array.select{ |a| a['age'].between?(26, 27) }
```

This will return you only the hash which has `age` between `26` and `27`

Or You can use **`include?`** to check for specific age

```
array.select{ |a| [26, 27].include? a['age'] }
```

Comment: Why would you use `between?` in this situation. There is nothing in OP's question that would suggest that it's appropriate.

Comment: @EricDuminil, when I see `include?`, I think *one of*, when I see `between?` I think *within the bounds of*. Both are equally easy to read, only one is what OP wanted. What if `26` and `27` were just an example?

Comment: @ndn: Both work fine with this example. I find `between?` even more readable than `include?` in this case : read as an english sentence, the first example is easier to parse IMHO.

Comment: @EricDuminil, a lot of things might work with the example's values. It doesn't mean they are correct in the general case.

Comment: @ndn: True, but only the OP knows what the general case is. Without more info, I find it harsh to say that this answer isn't appropriate.

Comment: @EricDuminil, OP stated what his case is - select for specific ages. Would you agree that `x.select { |e| (e['age'] - 26.5).abs < 1 }` is not simply obscure, but incorrect solution to the problem? If yes - that is the principal difference with `#between?`?

Comment: I am not arguing the correctness of answer for the specific solution **but normally in such scenarios you will select the results between some specific range and there you don't want to add each and every number in an array**

Comment: Let's say you need to select records whose age lies around 20 to 40 you don't want to add 20 elements in that array

Comment: Again you can use `(20..40).to_a`  but `between?` is doing same for you right?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, I would agree if OP asked for ages between *x* and *y* and not the ages *x* and *y*. There are plenty of reasons to ask for specific ages. My objection is that code should say what you say when describing your problem. He wants *x* and *y*, not between *x* and *y*.